# How can I reduce the following stream of strings to a boolean value

Tags: java

I have following stream written as so:

```
private static Set<Integer> validBinNumberLength =  new HashSet<>();

boolean valid = binDataRequest.getAccountBinNumbers().stream().reduce(true, (subTotal, element) ->
                    Boolean.logicalAnd(subTotal, validBinNumberLength.contains(element.length())));
```

I want to make sure that the length of all account numbers are within the domain of validNumberBinLength.

I am getting the error that subTotal is being seen as a string rather than boolean. How can I work around this?

Will the stream stop evaluating once a value is returned as false?. If not, how can I implement this lazy evaluation in the stream. I am doing this because I don't want to use old school for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` takes a `BinaryOperation`, meaning that both argument to the reduce function need to be the same, unless you use the slightly more complex variation which includes the `combiner`.

But it's a bit simpler, you can map and then use `allMatch`:

```
boolean valid = binDataRequest.getAccountBinNumbers().stream()
    .map(String::length)
    .allMatch(validBinNumberLength::contains);
```

Quick note on early exit: in the case of the `allMatch` function, it is designed to short-circuit once the value is `false`. In the case of reduce, it has no way of knowing that any value returned by the reducer is *final*, so there is no early exit, all the elements must be evaluated

edit: suggestion from @dnault to make it both shorter and clearer

Comment: Why is subtotal being seen as a string rather than a boolean? and cayou explain this code in more detail? what is function identity?

Comment: @Fernando `subTotal` of your code is the initial-value and intermediate result used by the reducer-function. Hence it should be a _boolean_ in order to compile, right?

Comment: how is the type specified initially?

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but I had to stare at `allMatch(Function.identity())` for a while before realizing it returns true iff all the stream elements are `true`. Does this alternate form seem simpler to you? `.stream().map(String::length).allMatch(validBinNumberLength::contains)`

Comment: tha'ts better. The problem is that it will evaluate all elements in the set. Is there any way we can stop the evaluation when a value is returned as false? or will stream use lazy evaluation in this case?

Comment: @Fernando it will most likely stop as soon as an element is false. (although that would be an implementation detail and could go one way or the other). Note that the reduce option would be more naive and would definitely run through all the elements)

Comment: @Fernando this should help confirm that the stream stops the evaluation once the result is definitely false: https://repl.it/repls/TragicSkinnyPerimeter

Comment: Can I somehow use more than one predicate in allMatch?

Comment: @Fernando yes, you have a variety of options for that. You can write a function that does all your tests at once and pass a reference to that one, you can use the `Predicate.and` and `.or` method to combine predicates if you have several predicates already